# traverse through nested objects

Tags: javascript, foreach

I'm using the function below to traverse through an object with arrays and change key names of objects. I'd like to know how to find out *when the traversing  has been done* - so when all the forEach loops have finished. I don't know how many child objects there are in advance.

```
function traverse(o) {
      if (o !== null && typeof o == 'object') {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([key, value]) => {
          if (key === 'Name') {
            o['name'] = o['Name'];
            delete o['Name'];
          }
          if (key === 'Children') {
            o['children'] = o['Children'];
            delete o['Children'];
            if (!o['children']) o['children'] = [];
          }
          traverse(value);
        });
      } 
    }
```

Comment: Well, you should know it finishes when the first `traverse` finishes. So `traverse(obj); console.log("it's done now");`

Comment: thanks! I would expect this to work if it was only one forEach loop, didn't expect it to work with multiple recursive loops.